Problem with joining session host to hostpool
So, I have to create registry token and update the values on each vm like manually in the azure portal. With powershell int he automation runbook
But the invoke command is not working for updating the values
Can someone tell me what I did wrong here?


try {
    "Logging in to Azure..."
    Connect-AzAccount -Identity
}
catch {
    Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
    throw $_.Exception
}

# Set the subscription (if not already set)
Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

$ResourceGroupName = "xxxxx1"
$HostPoolName = "wpxxxxxxxxx"


    # Check if the host pool exists
    $Hostpool = Get-AzWvdHostPool -Name $HostPoolName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    if (!$Hostpool) {
        Write-Host '', "Hostpool '$($HostPoolName)' doesn't exist. It will be created by TF"
    } else {
   
try {
    # Create token
    $RegistrationToken = New-AzWvdRegistrationInfo -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
        -HostPoolName $HostPoolName `
        -ExpirationTime (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().AddHours(2).ToString('yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffZ')

    Write-Host '', "Token created"
    Write-Output $RegistrationToken
} catch {
    throw $_.Exception
}

    }

$VMName = "001"

# Define the script block for registry update
$ScriptBlock = {
    param (
        [string]$RegistryPath,
        [string]$RegistryName,
        [string]$NewRegistryValueData
    )

    # Check if registry key exists, create if not
    if (-not (Test-Path $RegistryPath)) {
        try {
            New-Item -Path $RegistryPath -Force -ErrorAction Stop
            Write-Output "Registry key '$RegistryPath' created successfully."
        } catch {
            Write-Error "Failed to create registry key '$RegistryPath': $_"
        }
    }

    # Update registry value
    try {
        Set-ItemProperty -Path $RegistryPath -Name $RegistryName -Value $NewRegistryValueData -ErrorAction Stop
        Write-Output '', "Registry value updated"
    } catch {
        Write-Error -Message "Failed to update registry value: $_"
    }
}

# Define parameters for the script block
$Params = @{
    RegistryPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\RDInfraAgent"
    RegistryName = $RegistrationToken
    NewRegistryValueData = $RegistrationToken.Token
}

# Invoke the script block on the target VM
Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -VMName $VMName -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath $ScriptBlock -Parameter $Params



I'm unable to update the registry values in the vm but in the hostpool when I do it's updating. Im having trouble in this part as i'm new to azure. This is from azure automation runbook in the portal

Have you logged into session host to check RDAgentService on specific session?

the installation files for the rdinfra agent and bootloader are in the portal storage container. but no I without directly accesing the session host i have to do this

How are you connecting to the session for fetching the service from that VM?

I have generated PowerShell script for Azure Virtual Desktop Agent issues.

I'm unable to install the rdinfra and bootloader , I have the installation files, it's not to any vm yet , I have generated a token for the hostpool and updated the registry key value

The "RDAgentBootLoader" service, as part of the RDInfraAgent, is typically installed as part of the setup process for Windows Virtual Desktop (WVD) or Remote Desktop Services (RDS) environments.Refer this MS DOc

If you have the files already, follow the MS Doc for installing the agent.


Problem with joining session host to hostpool

Here is the troubleshoot process to troubleshoot Azure Virtual Desktop Agent(RDAgentBootLoader) issues.
Here is the PowerShell script to troubleshoot RDAgentBootLoader issues.
    # Define the PowerShell script as a here-string
$script = @"
# Check if the service RDAgentBootLoader is running
$serviceStatus = (Get-Service -Name "RDAgentBootLoader").Status
if ($serviceStatus -eq "Running") {
    Write-Output "RDAgentBootLoader service is already running."
} elseif ($serviceStatus -eq "Stopped") {
    # Start the service if it's stopped
    Start-Service -Name "RDAgentBootLoader"
    Write-Output "RDAgentBootLoader service started."
} else {
    # Restart the service if it's in any other state (e.g., Paused)
    Restart-Service -Name "RDAgentBootLoader"
    Write-Output "RDAgentBootLoader service restarted."
}

# Check if the service is now running
$serviceStatus = (Get-Service -Name "RDAgentBootLoader").Status
if ($serviceStatus -ne "Running") {
    Write-Output "RDAgentBootLoader service is still not running."
    
    # Define registry path
    $registryPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\RDInfraAgent"

    # Check if the registry key exists
    if (Test-Path $registryPath) {
        # Check if IsRegistered is set to 1
        $isRegistered = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name "IsRegistered" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).IsRegistered
        if ($isRegistered -ne 1) {
            # Set IsRegistered to 1 if it's not already set
            Set-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name "IsRegistered" -Value 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            Write-Output "IsRegistered set to 1."
        } else {
            Write-Output "IsRegistered is already set to 1."
        }

        # Check if RegistrationToken value exists
        $registrationToken = Get-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name "RegistrationToken" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        if ($registrationToken) {
            # Delete RegistrationToken value if it exists
            Remove-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name "RegistrationToken" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            Write-Output "RegistrationToken value deleted."
        } else {
            Write-Output "RegistrationToken value does not exist."
        }

        # Retrieve BrokerResourceIdURI from the registry
        $brokerResourceIdURI = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name "BrokerResourceIdURI" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)."BrokerResourceIdURI"
        if ($brokerResourceIdURI -ne $null) {
            # Check the health status of the RD Broker URI
            $brokerURIHealth = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "$brokerResourceIdURI/api/health" -UseBasicParsing
            if ($brokerURIHealth.StatusCode -eq 200) {
                Write-Output "RD Broker URI ($brokerResourceIdURI) is healthy."
            } else {
                Write-Output "RD Broker URI ($brokerResourceIdURI) is not healthy. Check network connectivity."
            }
        } else {
            Write-Output "BrokerResourceIdURI value does not exist in the registry."
        }
    } else {
        Write-Output "Registry key '$registryPath' does not exist."
    }
} else {
    Write-Output "RDAgentBootLoader service is running."
}
"@
#The script will run on every AVD session 
Connect-AzAccount -Identity
$resourceGroups = Get-AzResourceGroup | Where-Object { ($_.ResourceGroupName -like "Venkat") }

foreach ($rg in $resourceGroups) {
    $hostPoolObjects = Get-AzWvdHostPool -ResourceGroupName $rg.ResourceGroupName
    
    foreach ($hostPool in $hostPoolObjects) {
        $sessionHosts = Get-AzWvdSessionHost -ResourceGroupName $rg.ResourceGroupName -HostPoolName $hostPool.Name
        
        # Initialize an array to store modified session host names
        $modifiedSessionHosts = @()
        
        foreach ($sessionHost in $sessionHosts) {
            # Split the session host name by '/' and select the last element
            $sessionHostName = ($sessionHost.Name -split '/')[-1]
            $modifiedSessionHosts += $sessionHostName
        }
        
        # Output the modified session host names
        $modifiedSessionHosts
    }
}

Foreach($sessionhost in $modifiedSessionHosts){
Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName "Venkat" -VMName $modifiedSessionHosts -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -Script $script
}

Output:

Note: Make sure to assign the role to the identity before running the script in the automation account.



I'll try and let you know..

Follow the MS Doc for installing the RDInfraAgent if not already installed.

I don't understand what this does , I already have the installation files in the container in the portal , can I download from that?

If you already have the files, you can run this command with the token: msiexec /i Microsoft.RDInfra.RDAgent.Installer-x64-.msi /quiet REGISTRATIONTOKEN=. Check this link for detailed steps.

If I run that command in automation account how can I check if it's installed?

Run my script,if agent is installed, You will get the status is running.

I'm not getting any output -

Run the following command: Get-Service -Name "RDAgentBootLoader". If the agent is installed, you will see the status 'Service is running' indicating that the service is running.

It's saying service doesnt exist but i downloaded the serice and RDInfraagent.

In your script, the runbook is not taking the invoke command- so do i take the script part?

Share the automation account error.

I'm not getting any error, but after running the install command Start-Process , the rdinfraagent and bootloader is not getting downloaded.

Can you tell me a solution for I'm not able to see if service is installed in the vm  , do I need elevated access for.it?
